# Redis cache miss in spring boot Java

Tags: java, caching, redis, blocking

We are using `redis` cache through `cloudfoundry`. Ours is a spring boot Java project which uses method caching. One of our rest call is taking 1 min to fill up the cache. How can we block other restful call to wait until the first one finishes?

Sample code for caching

```
class MyComponent implements Component {

  @Cacheable("myCache")
  public Object myMethod(String key) {

  }
}
```

We notice that even though the caching process is in progress which is taking almost 1 minute, when other threads tries to hit the same method the request re-triggers

Comment: Welcome to SO. As written, your question is too board. Please show us what code you've tired and include why it doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code